# No OpenID endpoint found. - .Net OpenID

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, openid

I'm using .Net Open ID (http://code.google.com/p/dotnetopenid/)

I'm trying to add OpenId to a website we are using. I'm running the MVC sample out of the box and recieve the following error when selecting Yahoo/Google.

> No OpenID endpoint found.

The error happens on this line of code

```
return openid.CreateRequest(Request.Form["openid_identifier"]).RedirectingResponse.AsActionResult();
```

What does this error mean? And are there any common trouble-shooting things we can try?

Just to add the value in - Request.Form["openid_identifier"]

```
https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, check to make sure that Request.Form["openid_identifier"] is returning a valid URL (either the openid path to yahoo or google).  If it's not then you have an issue with your openid selector.  If it is, then the request is being made, but the openid provider isn't responding in time which causes you to get the "No OpenID endpoint found."  Try issuing the request again and see if it works a second subsequent time.

**UPDATE**

If you're running under a proxy you need to specify that

Example:

```
<defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true">  
    <proxy autoDetect="True" usesystemdefault="True"/>  
</defaultProxy>
```

Comment: Thanks, but no luck. The value is valid as updated in main question.

Comment: Could this be somthing to do with the webconnection? Proxy etc?

Comment: @Liam Are you running it using a proxy for your site?  That would most likely be a problem with google, since google generates your unique identifier based on the site's url.

Comment: I'm currently running this locally, lets say the network had a proxy. How would I go about overcomming this?

Comment: Resolved By Adding the following, 

<defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true">
            <proxy autoDetect="True" usesystemdefault="True"/>
        </defaultProxy>

Comment: @Liam great!  Google generates unique identifiers using your URL, so if you're under a proxy that will cause google to generate the wrong identifier.  I'm not sure if Yahoo does the same thing, but it's a major deal since a lot of users will log in using google.

Comment: I have the same problem with Google but it is intermittent. Not using proxies either. It might be a timeout issues, is there a way of changing the expected response time from Provider?

Comment: I have the same problem. But using the defaultProxy settings didn't solve it. Any other clues?