# no openid endpoint found

Tags: c#, dotnetopenauth

what changes are needed to made in web.config file to prevent this exception i am using dotnet open id for implementing open id.

```
using (OpenIdRelyingParty openid = new OpenIdRelyingParty())
            {
                IAuthenticationRequest request = openid.CreateRequest(this.txtOpenId.Text);
```

and at this point an exception is generated no openid endpoint found for example in case i am typing claimid.com/openid

Comment: You will need to provide some more info Mac!

Comment: In order to say what changes need to be applied to something this something needs to be shown first. Also in .NET each exception is usually accompanied by a stack trace which helps better understand and pinpoint the problem.

Comment: i have updated the question hope now it helps

Comment: your update shows neither *the something* that needs to be updated (your web.config) nor the full exception stack trace you are getting, thus your update doesn't bring any value to your question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [No OpenID endpoint found. - .Net OpenID](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1588502/no-openid-endpoint-found-net-openid)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and I solved it setting up logs for DotNetOpenAuth (http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/developers/help/loggingdebugging-dotnetopenauth-with-log4net/). If you are using Log4Net you can try this:

```
<appender name="FileApp_DotNetOpenAuth" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="Logs/DotNetOpenAuth.log" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="Size" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
    <maximumFileSize value="5MB" />
    <staticLogFileName value="true" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>

<logger name="DotNetOpenAuth">
    <level value="ALL" />         
    <appender-ref ref="FileApp_DotNetOpenAuth"/>
  </logger>
```

Then check the log file DotNetOpenAuth.log for your current error. It would help you troubleshoot the problem.

Answer (score 0):

[No OpenID endpoint found. - .Net OpenID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1588502/no-openid-endpoint-found-net-openid)

Hard to say with the little info provided, but that error is fairly common, infact it's been asked before! Have a look at the link above!