# Authentication with Google using OpenOAuthProvider

Tags: asp.net, dotnetopenauth

I created the default ASP.NET project template in Visual Studio and went to the `AuthConfig` inside `App_Start` folder. Then I uncommented the following line:

```
OpenAuth.AuthenticationClients.AddGoogle();
```

I got the button for logging in with Google like this:

[image]
When I click on Google button, I'm getting this error:

```
An exception of type 'DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.ProtocolException' 
occurred in DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: No OpenID endpoint found.
```

**WE.config file**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!--
      For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
      http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
      -->
    <configuration>
      <configSections>


     <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
        <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
      </configSections>          
      <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
        <pages>


<namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
  </namespaces>
<controls>
  <add assembly="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" tagPrefix="webopt" />
</controls></pages>
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" defaultUrl="~/" />
</authentication>
<profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider">
  <providers>


<add name="DefaultProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</profile>
<membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</membership>
<roleManager defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
  <providers>


         <add name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
          </providers>
        </roleManager>

        <sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
          <providers>
            <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
          </providers>
        </sessionState>
      </system.web>
      <runtime>


     <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.Core" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
          </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
      </runtime>
      <entityFramework>
        <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
      </entityFramework>

    <appSettings>
          <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
        </appSettings>

    </configuration>
```

Please help me. What am I missing?

Comment: did u created the outh key in Google developers?

Comment: Can you provide your web.config file? You can also set up logging in your project with log4net. Then you will definitely find out what's wrong. I provided you with a link on how to set up logging for OpenAuth: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3530753/no-openid-endpoint-found.

Comment: @Webruster - As per my knowledge with new template its not required to create the application , please correct me if i am wrong

Comment: @Saasen - Updated question with web.config file

Comment: Thanks. I'm a little confused though. Are you using the built-in OAuth in the project template or are you using [DotNetOpenAuth](https://github.com/DotNetOpenAuth)? Also, when adding Google authentication, you need to provide a client-id and a client secret. Is this MVC4 or MVC5?

Comment: @Liquid i am asking regarding Google not asp.net application, for Google they will provide a auth key

Comment: using the built-in OAuth in the project template its not MVC it is Default Web Form Application

Comment: @Webruster That i have created having both the keys how will use it here that i am not able to understand.

Comment: Actually i have seen some documentation which stating that you have to uncomment the OpenAuth.AuthenticationClients.AddGoogle(); line from the Authconfig.cs  and its done we can authenticate with google for login. Is it right or wrong ??

Comment: Other people using this solution have had troubles with their proxy server. Are you on a corporate network? If yes, you should probably look at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa91de1e.aspx). Also, why are you using MVC4? Do you have Visual Studio 2012?

Comment: @liquid I have implemented using Open auth and its working fine for me

Comment: @Liquid Created a Room if you can then i can help you out. here is the [link](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92118/outh-autentication)

Comment: @Liquid did you tried that process ?

Answer (score 1):

Actually this kind of implementation (OpenId) is [deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23780039/mvc-google-login-openid-auth-request-contains-an-unregistered-domain). If it is possible, you should change to MVC5. In MVC5, it's very [straightforward](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on). That solution will still work. If you can't, you need to either write this [yourself](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth) or use a third-party component which uses OAuth2 to communicate with Google. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23780039/mvc-google-login-openid-auth-request-contains-an-unregistered-domain) for more information around the deprecated functionality.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned in your chat comment using  `Web Form Application`.On click Event of `Google`.

```
protected void lnkbtngplus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
try 
{ 
var Googleurl = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&redirect_uri=" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["googleplus_redirect_url"] + "&scope=googleapis.com/auth/…" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["googleplus_client_id"]; 
Session["loginWith"] = "google"; 
Response.Redirect(Googleurl); 
} 

catch (Exception ex) 
{ 
Master.Messages(ex.Message); 
} 
}
```

On your **Redirect url** you can collect the parameter values as shown below

```
  try
                {
                    var url = Request.Url.Query;
                    if (url != "")
                    {
                        string queryString = url.ToString();
                        char[] delimiterChars = { '=' };
                        string[] words = queryString.Split(delimiterChars);
                        string code = words[1];
                        SocialNetwork.GoogleUserOutputData json_data = SocialNetwork.Googlemethod(code);
                        String email = String.Empty;
                        String id = String.Empty;
                        email = json_data.email;
                        id = json_data.given_name;
                        if (email != null && email != "")
                        {
                            txtFname.Text = id;
                            txtemail.Text = email;


                        }


                    }
                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }
```

In **SocialNetwork class file** i have these following methods

```
#region Google



     protected static string Parameters;


     public static GoogleUserOutputData Googlemethod(string code)
     {
         GoogleUserOutputData serStatus1 = new GoogleUserOutputData();
         string json_data = string.Empty;
         if (code != null)
         {
             //get the access token 
             HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token");
             webRequest.Method = "POST";
             Parameters = "code=" + code + "&client_id=" + googleplus_client_id + "&client_secret=" + googleplus_client_sceret + "&redirect_uri=" + googleplus_redirect_url + "&grant_type=authorization_code";
             byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Parameters);
             webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
             webRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
             Stream postStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream();
             // Add the post data to the web request
             postStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
             postStream.Close();

             WebResponse response = webRequest.GetResponse(); 
             postStream = response.GetResponseStream();
             StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(postStream);
             string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();

             GooglePlusAccessToken serStatus = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GooglePlusAccessToken>(responseFromServer);//JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GooglePlusAccessToken>(responseFromServer);
             //GooglePlusAccessToken serStatus = new GooglePlusAccessToken();
             if (serStatus != null)
             {
                 string accessToken = string.Empty;
                 accessToken = serStatus.access_token;

                 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken))
                 {
                     using (var w = new WebClient())
                     {
                         json_data = w.DownloadString("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token=" + accessToken);
                         serStatus1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GoogleUserOutputData>(json_data);
                     }
                 }
                 else
                 { }
             }
             else
             { }
         }
         return serStatus1;
     }

     public class GoogleUserOutputData
     {
         public string id { get; set; }
         public string name { get; set; }
         public string given_name { get; set; }
         public string email { get; set; }
         public string picture { get; set; }
     }
     public class GooglePlusAccessToken
     {
         public string access_token { get; set; }
         public string token_type { get; set; }
         public int expires_in { get; set; }
         public string id_token { get; set; }
         public string refresh_token { get; set; }
     }

    #endregion
```

adding the screenshot of autentication from google based on my working example as provided above

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may missing ConfigureAuth for Google Authentication by add following code:

```
 app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions()
        {
            ClientId = "*****************.googleusercontent.com",
            ClientSecret = "********************"

        });
```

On Startup.Auth.cs

```
 public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Configure the db context, user manager and signin manager to use a single instance per request
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

        // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
        // and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
        // Configure the sign in cookie
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
                // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
            }
        });            
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

        // Enables the application to temporarily store user information when they are verifying the second factor in the two-factor authentication process.
        app.UseTwoFactorSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));

        // Enables the application to remember the second login verification factor such as phone or email.
        // Once you check this option, your second step of verification during the login process will be remembered on the device where you logged in from.
        // This is similar to the RememberMe option when you log in.
        app.UseTwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie);

        // Uncomment the following lines to enable logging in with third party login providers
        //app.UseMicrosoftAccountAuthentication(
        //    clientId: "",
        //    clientSecret: "");

        //app.UseTwitterAuthentication(
        //   consumerKey: "",
        //   consumerSecret: "");

        //app.UseFacebookAuthentication(
        //   appId: "",
        //   appSecret: "");

        // The same with Facebook, Twitter, MicrosoftAccount 
        app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions()
        {
            ClientId = "*****************.googleusercontent.com",
            ClientSecret = "********************"

        });
```